# Disabling desktop switching animation on El Capitan

Tags: macos, desktop

On Yosemite I used totalspaces to modify this behaviour as well as having a grid layout... I understand that totalspaces no longer works without doing some system modifications.

The animation I wish to eliminate/speed up is the default space switching animation, which for me is invoked by either swiping left/right with three fingers or ctrl+ left/right.

Is it possible to kill or speed this up?

Edit: One year later, we're on Sierra now.... please send help

Edit: Two years later, I still check this thread and any solution still appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify what animation you're trying to change.

Comment: I agree - what animation are you looking to eliminate? How do you switch desktops? what hardware is in play?

Comment: I think I know, I have the same problem. The animation in question is when the entire current screen slides away to the left or right, and another desktop slides in. This can be achieved by swiping with three fingers on the trackpad sideways, or [Ctrl]+[RightArrow/LeftArrow]. It's really annoying, because if you fullscreen a text editor, and quickly want to [Cmd]+[Tab] to a browser and reload it, you have to wait for the animation to finish, otherwise the key presses goes to the editor, not the browser.

Comment: Yes this is it exactly!! Super annoying for switching between desktops often.

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting this into Terminal.app:

`defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0.1`

It is supposed to

> Make all animations faster that are used by Mission Control.

Source: http://www.defaults-write.com/10-terminal-commands-to-speed-up-your-mac-in-os-x-el-capitan/

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't quite right - It just enables the mission control commands (like showing all open windows), but not the desktop switching animation.